# OneToOne foreign key saving issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "applicant")
    public class Applicant implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8634638904962909584L;

        // Primary id required by Hibernate
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "applicant_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
            private Long applicantId; // Unique id for each applicant

        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
        @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", referencedColumnName= "applicant_id")
        private DS1350 ds1350;


        public Applicant () {

        }

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ds_1350")

    public class DS1350 implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7370747595057569296L;

        // Primary id required by Hibernate
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ds_1350_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
        private Long ds1350Id;

        @Column(name = "applicant_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    //    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    //  @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "applicant"))
        private Long applicantId; // Unique id for each applicant

        @Column(name = "ds1350_no", length = 50)
        private String ds1350Number;

    }

   public class ApplicantDaoTest {
        @Autowired
        private ApplicantDao applicantDao;

        private Applicant applicant;
        private DS1350 ds1350 = new DS1350();

        @BeforeClass
        public static void beforeClass() {
        }


        @AfterClass
        public static void afterClass() {
        }


        @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.initApplicant();
        }

        @After
        public void teardown() {
        }

        private void initApplicant() {
            applicant = new Applicant();

            applicant.setFirstName("John");

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            applicant.setDob(calendar);

            applicant.setSsn("123456789");
            applicant.setCreatedBy("JUNIT");
            applicant.setCreatedDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            applicant.setModifiedBy("JUnit");
            applicant.setModifiedDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            this.initDS1350();

        }


        private void initDS1350 () {        
            ds1350.setDs1350Number("ds1350Number");
            ds1350.setCreatedBy("JUNIT");
            ds1350.setCreatedDate(Calendar.getInstance());  

            applicant.setDs1350(ds1350);
        }

        @Test
        public void testSaveApplicant() {
            Long applicantId = applicantDao.saveApplicant(applicant);
            applicant = applicantDao.getApplicantByPrimaryKey(applicantId);
            assertTrue("ds1350Number".equals(applicant.getDs1350().getDs1350Number()));
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for ds1350 and applicant class. I use hibernate session save() to save the applicant where ds1350 is included in the applicant object. I have OneToMany which are perfectly fine but this OneToOne is not working. applicant.getDs1350() throws a NullPointerException as the foreign key (applicant_id in ds1350) is saved as null and applicantDao.getApplicantByPrimaryKey(applicantId) cannot fetch the ds1350 object.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the `Applicant` and `DS1350` entities and save them?

Comment: private void initDS1350 () {
  ds1350 = new DS1350();
  
  ds1350.setDs1350Number("ds1350Number");
  ds1350.setCreatedBy("JUNIT");
  ds1350.setCreatedDate(Calendar.getInstance()); 
  
  applicant.setDs1350(ds1350);
 }

Comment: public class ApplicantDaoTest {
 @Autowired
 private ApplicantDao applicantDao;
 
 // Domain objects
 private DS1350 ds1350 = new DS1350();

Comment: I create the Applicant in a method which I call from the setup()

Comment: Post the full ds1350 and applicant classes here please.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of " @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)". You're telling it to fetch eagerly in your OneToOne annotation but then telling it to fetch lazily with that @Fetch annotation.

Also, make sure that your join column on the ds1350 field has the correct FK field referenced (if the field in Applicant isn't called id).

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id", referencedColumnName= "applicant_id")
private DS1350 ds1350;
```

Another point that i missed at first is that you're using

```
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
```

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#IDENTITY):
"Indicates that the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column."

If you're not manually assigning the idea when you're creating the link the id won't be persisted. Using @GeneratedValue(strategy=AUTO) will tell the database that it needs to generate the ID for your child class (DS1350). This is A fix, but might not be what you're going for.

Also, based on your update you're referencing the wrong foreign key in the join column, and the association from your ds1350 to your applicant looks suspect, try something like this:

```
 //in applicant
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ds1350_id", referencedColumnName= "applicant_id")
    private DS1350 ds1350;

   //in ds1350
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="applicant", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private Applicant applicant; // Unique id for each applicant
```

I haven't tested that.

Comment: both the Applcant and DS1350 has fields are named as applicant_id, PK in Applicant and FK in DS1350, should I use referencedColumnName= "applicantId" in the Applicant as referencedColumnName= "applicant_id" then?

Comment: Tried with the suggested changes, no luck, same issue. foreign key in the DS1350 not getting saved.

Comment: referencedColumnName = "applicant_id"

Comment: @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicant_id")
    private DS1350 ds1350;                               This one works perfectly for OneToMany but not for OneToOne

Comment: Di not understand this: Also, make sure that your join column on the ds1350 field has the correct FK field referenced (if the field in Applicant isn't called id). Di I need to add anything in the DS1350 class?

Comment: I am out of ideas now. Please help.

Comment: Added the Applicant and DS1350 classes, please have a look. Thanks. zmf: do you have an email id where I can send the complete flow? Please let me know.

Comment: I used @Transactional before my test method and seems like the applicant and ds1350 records are created because I get a new applicant_id but I do not see this in the database. The rows are not there in the database table. I tried session flush() also, no luck, Is there any way to force the commit?

Comment: Thanks zmf, I have used   //in ds1350
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="applicant", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private Long applicantId; in the ds1350 by commenting @column because I cannot use both together. it complains that it caanot find column by name applicantId.

Comment: Right. That was my mistake. What I meant to do there is include a reference to an applicant on ds1350.

Comment: When I use exactly what you said, I get this: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-persistence-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @OneToOne property: com.dtis.dac.domain.DS1350.applicantId

Comment: Got it to work. First one needs to set the parent to the child and then back child to the parent after declaring OneToOne on both the classes.